# 9patch AAPT: error: file failed to compile

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm trying to work with a 9patch image format but I get this error when I try to build the app:

```
AAPT: error: file failed to compile
```

Any reasons why this could happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that the 9patch failed to compile was 9patch bad format - the 9patch indicating pixels wasn't fully black (#000000) but some of them was grey, fixing those pixels to pure black fixed the problem

Comment: mine are pure black or pure transparent.  how can i get gradlew to give me more details?

Comment: This was the case for me too! I checked the black pixels, and turns out they were RGB(1,1,1) instead of RGB(0,0,0)

Answer (score 1):

Having opened the 9patch in an image editor while editing it at the same time in Android Studio can also cause this error, I guess its since AS can't write the 9patch file when compiling.

Answer (score 1):

For me this was because the top-left pixel was black instead of transparent.